# RSpec FactoryGirl namespace wrong default lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Struggling with RSpec 3.1, FactoryGirl 4.5 and Rails 3.2

`billing/plan_spec.rb` is ok, but whenever I try to run `billing/payment_spec.rb` it fails with `uninitialized constant Billing::Payment::BillingPlan (NameError)`

Any ideas why FactoryGirl is looking for `Billing::Payment::BillingPlan` and not `Billing::Plan` ?

Any tips how to solve it?

Files:

```
# factories\billing_plans.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :billing_plan, :class => 'Billing::Plan' do
    user
  end
end
```

-

```
# factories\billing_payments.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :billing_payment, :class => 'Billing::Payment' do
    billing_plan
    amount 1234
  end
end
```

-

```
# billing/payment_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Billing::Payment do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(build(:billing_payment)).to be_valid
  end

  it 'requires an amount' do
    expect(build(:billing_payment, amount: nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

-

```
# billing/plan_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Billing::Plan do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(build(:billing_plan)).to be_valid
  end

  it 'requires an user' do
    expect(build(:billing_plan, user: nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

-

```
# billing/payment.rb
class Billing::Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :billing_plan
  attr_accessible :amount, :billing_plan_id

  validates :amount, presence: true
end
```

-

```
# billing/plan.rb
class Billing::Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id

  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Could you share `billing/payment_spec.rb` and your `billing_plan.rb`, please?

Comment: @AlexP just added more info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having this issue and tried the above recommendations and none worked, here's what I did:

my model: `RewardSystem::AchievementTemplate`

my spec for this test is in: `/spec/models/reward_system/achievement_template_spec.rb`

So then if you change the model name in the spec file to the namespaced version, it works (assuming you haven't removed `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` from the `rails_helper.rb` file)

**FILES:**

factories/achievement_template.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :achievement_template do
  end
end
```

model/achievement_template_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RewardSystem::AchievementTemplate, type: :model do
  context "Awarding" do
    it "should award coins for unlocking an achievement" do
      achievement = FactoryGirl.create(:reward_template)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `:class => Billing::Plan` or `:class => '::Billing::Plan'`?

Comment: This should have worked. Does if fail with the same error?

Comment: Running into the exact same issue and this fix doesn't work. Same error.